# Is eval() non mandatory in parsing json objects?

Tags: javascript, html, json, eval

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2>JSON Object Creation in JavaScript</h2> 

<p>
Name: <span id="jname"></span><br />
Eval Name: <span id="evalname"></span><br />
<p>
<script>
var yyyy= {
"name":"John Johnson",
"street":"Oslo West 555",
"age":33,
"phone":"555 1234567"};


document.getElementById("jname").innerHTML = yyyy.name;
document.getElementById("evalname").innerHTML = eval(yyyy).name;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

i am getting out put as below this is same with and without eval()

**JSON Object Creation in JavaScript**

Name: John Johnson

Eval Name: John Johnson

Comment: There is no such thing as a json object and that is not json

Comment: See http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: That is a normal js object...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`yyyy` isn't JSON. It's a JavaScript object. So in this case, you don't need `eval` whatsoever. When you deal with JSON, you should use `JSON.parse` instead of `eval`.

`eval` simply returns the object you passed to it, without modifying it. So it's superfluous here.

Comment: Better: "You **should** always use `JSON.parse` instead of `eval`" (because faster and without the inherent security issues of `eval`).

Answer (score 1):

JSON is a serialization protocol, inspired by (and named for) Javascript.  What you have is an actual Javascript object.  JSON would arrive at the browser as a response from a server, and you would have to use something to decode the string into a Javascript object.  `JSON.parse` is the best option.  `eval` also works for this, but is a very blunt and dangerous instrument.

You can use JSON encoders on the server side to insert Javascript objects into server-generated Javascript, which may be how you got the code you are showing.  In that case, you don't need a decoder at all, you can simply use the object as you are showing in your first example.